# recursive search for file with .log extension in all sub directories

Tags: tcl

What is the command in TCL to do recursive search for file with .log extension in current directory and sub directories.

I have tried **glob -type f *.log** but it only looks in current directory.

Comment: Tcl has not command for recursive search in directories. You sould implement this logic by yourself, using recursive calls or other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The `fileutil` package in Tcllib is ideal for this sort of thing. In particular, [`fileutil::find`](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.html#12) does exactly what you want.

```
package require fileutil

# We need a helper procedure here. This is a trivial wrapper round [string match]
proc is_log {name} {
    return [string match *.log $name]
}
set log_files [fileutil::find [pwd] is_log]
```